# Bluetooth keyboard connects, is detected as keyboard, but won't type any key and disconnects quickly

Tags: linux, keyboard, bluetooth

Last year, I bought a cheap Bluetooth keyboard to use the computer from far away. I already had a Bluetooth mouse to match, and it works nicely.

This keyboard, however, has issues. I connect to it using `bluetoothctl`, and after some tries it pairs successfully and can connect. The problem is, it quickly disconnects due to lack of input, and I guess that's normal since it is trying to save power.

Whenever I type a key, it quickly reconnects, but as I type the keys do nothing, it does not write on the current window nor have any effect such as toggling Caps Lock or running a shortcut.

The keyboard connects fine according to `bluetoothctl` (connecting then disconnecting):

```
[CHG] Device [MAC address] Connected: yes
[CHG] Device [MAC address] Connected: no
```

It is also detected by `udev` as an input method (connecting then disconnecting):

```
UDEV  [156063.176719] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256
SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth
DEVTYPE=link
SEQNUM=4586
USEC_INITIALIZED=156063176604
SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0:256
SYSTEMD_WANTS=bluetooth.target
SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS=bluetooth.target
TAGS=:systemd:

UDEV  [156063.520071] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256
SUBSYSTEM=bluetooth
DEVTYPE=link
SEQNUM=4587
USEC_INITIALIZED=156063176604
SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0:256
SYSTEMD_WANTS=bluetooth.target
SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS=bluetooth.target
TAGS=:systemd:
```

`libinput debug-events` shows nothing, if the BT keyboard connects, disconnects or is typed to. So I guess it doesn't get that far as to be registered as a keyboard.

I tried changing desktop environment, but it doesn't work either on GNOME or Sway.

This same keyboard pairs fine and works without any problems when connecting to an Android phone, also several other Bluetooth devices (notably the aforementioned mouse and a headphone that I use daily) work great.

What might be the issue with this keyboard and how can I correctly connect so I can type with it?